# Disable mousemove on click

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm experimenting on a drag 'n' drop, this is my code here:

```
$('.box-title').live('mousedown click', function(e)
{
    var self = $(this);
    var Box = self.parent('#box');

    if(e.type == 'mousedown')
    {
        $(window).mousemove(function(e)
        {
            Box.css({ cursor: 'move', top: e.pageY - 15, left: e.pageX - 125 });
        });
    }
    else if(e.type == 'click')
    {
        Box.css({ cursor: 'default', top: e.pageY - 15, left: e.pageX - 125 });
    }
});
```

On mousedown, it should initiate the dragging effect by moving the mouse, after that if I want to dock/drop the box where I want it to me, I click on it it should disable the moving but if I click on it, it doesn't stop moving - just keeps following my mouse. How can you stop the dragging?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unbind the `mousemove` handler which is *still* attached currently, for example:

```
function setPos(e) {
  //can be $('#box') in this case...
  $(this).parent('#box').css({ cursor: 'move', top: e.pageY - 15, left: e.pageX - 125 });
}    
$('.box-title').live('mousedown click', function(e) {
    if(e.type == 'mousedown') {
        $(window).mousemove(setPos);
    }
    else if(e.type == 'click') {
        $(window).unbind('mousemove', setPos);
    }
});
```

Or, in jQuery 1.4.3+ that `.live()` handler can be a bit cleaner:

```
$('.box-title').live({
  mousedown: function() {
    $(window).mousemove(setPos);
  },
  click: function() {
    $(window).unbind('mousemove', setPos);
  }
});
```

---

As an aside, it *appears* you have multiple `id="box"` elements in the page...make sure to use classes in those cases, in this code `$(this).parent('#box')` would be `$(this).closest('.box')` instead.

Comment: Can't do anything without you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

`$(window).unbind('mousemove')`

in your click event.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(e.type == 'click')
{
    $(window).unbind('mousemove')
}
```

But really you should name the event so you only unbind the appropriate event listener.

Bind : `$(window).bind('mousemove.dragging', function(){});`

Unbind : `$(window).unbind('mousemove.dragging', function(){});`