# Stopping mouseMoved

Tags: java, mouseevent

I was wondering how to stop mousedMoved from being fired. I've been googling but can't find an answer. Is there a method for this? I'm using eclipse and went through the mouseevent methods but just can't find anything.

```
    public class Drawing extends JPanel {

private ArrayList<Point> pointList;
private int counter = 0;

public Drawing() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setBackground(Color.white);

    pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
    addMouseListener(new MouseTrackerListener());


}

public void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
    super.paintComponent(pen);


    for (int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++) {
        Point p = pointList.get(i);
        pen.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 10, 10);
    }

}

private class MouseTrackerListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        counter++;
        if (counter % 2 != 0) {
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseTrackerListener());


        } else {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        Point point = e.getPoint();
        pointList.add(point);

        repaint();

    }
}
```

Comment: Stop listening to it?

Comment: Remove the `MouseMotionListener` which is triggering the updates?

Comment: how about adding a condition to the code not to execute.. so even if it fired, it will not execute the code inside the listener?

Comment: @John3136 what do you mean by that? I'm new to this section sorry

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do I remove it? Idk how to stop it once its running

Comment: That will depend on how you registered it in the first place

Comment: @DyrandzFamador I have it activated in my mouseClicked method so whenever it is clicked, it also moves. I've tried putting it in a conditional so that it wouldn't add the MouseMotionListener after every other click but idk

Comment: post your code ben no one will guess the answer.

Comment: @ben, it would be better if you post some code where you implement adding the listener and calling it.. so we could understand more what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @ben, in what scenario you want to remove the `mousemoved listener`.? since you add that listener then you probably want to use that.

Comment: @DyrandzFamador so basically in my program, the user clicks once to get the mouse to start drawing and if they want to stop, they click again and so on if they want to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a `boolean` to toggle if it's on drawing status or not. you name the `boolean` like `isDrawingMode`

so when you click the mouse.. you set it to false, if you click it again, it will become true;

all you have to do is to toggle the `boolean isDrawingMode` when the mouse was clicked

so your `mousemoved listener` will look like this

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        if (!isDrawingMode) return; //if isDrawingMode is false, it will not trigger to draw
        Point point = e.getPoint();
        pointList.add(point);

        repaint();

}
```

Comment: omg thank you so much! all this time I been messing with mouseClicked but haven't touched the mouseMoved ahah thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> For Java

You could use a common base class for your listeners and in it, have a static method to turn the listeners on or off:

```
public abstract class BaseMouseListener implements ActionListener{

    private static boolean active = true;
    public static void setActive(boolean active){
        BaseMouseListener.active = active;
    }

    protected abstract void doPerformAction(ActionEvent e);

    @Override
    public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(active){
            doPerformAction(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Your listeners would have to implement doPerformAction() instead of actionPerformed().

> More info :
>   [How to temporarily disable event listeners in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722835/how-to-temporarily-disable-event-listeners-in-swing)

I don't know which language u using or what is your code.
In Jquery i generally use the following  2 methods code

M1: to unbind one event of another.

OR
M2: You should add event.stopPropagation() at the end of this event call to stop propogation..

> M1 code sample:

```
else if(e.type == 'click')
{
    $(window).unbind('mousemove')
}
But really you should name the event so you only unbind the appropriate event listener.

Bind : $(window).bind('mousemove.dragging', function(){});

Unbind : $(window).unbind('mousemove.dragging', function(){});
```

> M2 Code sample:

```
$("#rightSubMenu").mousemove(function(e){
  // You code...
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

> Extra Info

For more info just see following tags
[Disable mousemove on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587632/disable-mousemove-on-click)
[How to stop mousemove() from executing when the element under the mouse moves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873153/how-to-stop-mousemove-from-executing-when-the-element-under-the-mouse-moves)

Comment: his using java. it would be better if you provide a java code

Comment: It's tagged but if you can't see it, I'm using Java